# Optimization of minimum cost path not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will find the path in n*n matrix with minimum cost (every coordinate has a pre-defined cost). Cost of path is defined as the sum of all coordinate costs. The first line of input contains the size of a matrix and the following n lines are table rows. Last two lines of code are 1. begin coordinates 2. end coordinates. Output is the minimum path cost.

Example input :

```
5
0 1 2 1 1
0 0 1 5 1
1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 7 0
1 8 0 0 0
0 0
4 4
```

Output should be 0

This is code with memoization (it works without memoization but it's slow)

```
import copy
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(9000)

INF = 100000

n = int(input())

memo = {}

def input_matrix(n) :
    p = []
    for i in range(n) :
        p.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
    return p

def min_cost(matrix, x, y, end_x, end_y) :
    if x == end_x and y == end_y :
        return 0
    if (x, y) in memo :
        return memo[(x, y)]
    if x == len(matrix) or y == len(matrix) or x == -1 or y == -1 or matrix[y][x] == -1:
        return INF

    z = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
    z[y][x] = -1

    memo[(x, y)] = min(
        min_cost(z, x+1, y, end_x, end_y)+matrix[y][x],
        min_cost(z, x-1, y, end_x, end_y)+matrix[y][x],
        min_cost(z, x, y+1, end_x, end_y)+matrix[y][x],
        min_cost(z, x, y-1, end_x, end_y)+matrix[y][x]
    )
    return memo[(x, y)]

matrix = input_matrix(n)

begin_coords = list(map(int, input().split()))
end_coords = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(min_cost(matrix, begin_coords[0], begin_coords[1], end_coords[0], end_coords[1]))
```

Comment: You might want to describe what you're doing a little, and provide a (small) sample input with the expected output.

Comment: Also if this is an optimization which does not work, is there some code without this which does work correctly on small inputs? Is the memoization the optimization you mentioned?

Comment: Code is working properly without memoization.

Comment: I just tried this and it still returns 1. Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: @gimli I realized that I made a change that basically removed the cache. Anyway the problem is that during the recursive calls it seems like it computes `1` for `x=0` and `y=1`, I'm trying to understand why is that.

Comment: In any case it fails on a `n=3` example: `[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [1,1,0]`, this is probably easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your use of the cache is not correct. Consider the following example, in which your code returns `1` instead of `0`:

```
3
0 0 1
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 0
2 2
```

If you try to follow the code flow you'll see that your algorithms searches the matrix in the following way:

```
0 -> 0 -> 1 -> x
          |
1 <- 0 <- 0 -> x
|
1 -> 1 -> 0
```

Moreover you are setting the value in the matrix at `-1` when you perform the recursive call, so when you finally reach the goal the matrix is:

```
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 0
```

Sure, you are copying the matrices, but during a recursive call the whole path followed to reach that point will still be `-1`.

I.e. when your code finds `2, 2` it returns `0`. The call on `1, 2` tries to compute the value for `0, 2` but returns `inf` because the bottom-left corner is `-1`, the call on `1, 3` and `1, 1` return `+inf` too. So for `x=1, y=2` we get the correct value `1`. The code backtracks, obtaining the matrix:

```
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
-1  1 0
```

And we have `1,2 -> 1` in our `memo`. We have to finish the call for `0, 2`, which again tries `-1, 2`, `0, 3` and `0, 1` all of these return `+inf` and hence we compute `0 2 -> 2` which is correct.

Now however things start to go wrong. The call at `0, 1` has already tried to go `1, 1` but that returns `+inf` since the value is set to `-1`, the same holds for all other recursive calls. Hence we set `0, 1 -> 3` **which is wrong**.

Basically by setting the value in the matrix to `-1` during recursive calls you have prevent the recursive call for `0, 1` to go right and get the correct value of `1`.

The issue appears in the cached version because now *every time we return to `0 1` we get the wrong value. Without cache the code is able to reach `0 1` by a path not coming from `1 1` and hence discover that `0 1 -> 1`.

Instead of cachine I would use a dynamic programming approach. Fill the matrix with `+inf` values. Start at the goal position and put a `0` there, then compute the neighbouring values by row/column:

```
def min_cost(matrix, x, y, end_x, end_y):
    n = len(matrix)
    memo = [[float('+inf') for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    memo[end_y, end_x] = 0
    changed = True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for x in range(n):
            for y in range(n):
                m = matrix[y][x]
                old_v = memo[y][x]
                memo[y][x] = min(
                    memo[y][x], 
                    m + min(memo[h][k] for h in (y-1, y+1) if 0 <= h < n for k in (x-1, x+1) if 0 <= k < n)
                )
                if memo[y][x] != old_v:
                    changed = True
    return memo[y, x]
```

However this is still not as efficient as it could be. If you apply dynamic programming correctly you will end up with the [Bellman-Ford Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). Your grid is just a graph where each vertex `x, y` has four outgoing edges (except those on the border).

Comment: Now I understand. I falsely assumed that the error at 1, 1 would not occur because checking whether coordinates are in the cache occurs before checking if the value at coordinates is -1, so I thought that when 1, 1 is accessed, minimum path for that point is stored in memo so it is returned instead of inf.